# How to calculate the difference between time inputs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate my work time. It works fine when I input

```
08:00 - 09:00 = 01:00
```

But when I input this time

```
23:30 - 01:30 = 10:00
```

It should return `02:00`

```js
function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function diffTime(start, end) {
  var s = start.split(":"),
    sMin = +s[1] + s[0] * 60,
    e = end.split(":"),
    eMin = +e[1] + e[0] * 60,
    diff = eMin - sMin;
    
  if (diff < 0) {
    sMin -= 12 * 60;
    diff = eMin - sMin
  }
  var h = Math.floor(diff / 60),
    m = diff % 60;
  return "" + pad(h) + ":" + pad(m);
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('delay').value = diffTime(
    document.getElementById('timeOfCall').value,
    document.getElementById('timeOfResponse').value
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="timeOfCall">
<input type="time" id="timeOfResponse">
<button type="button" id="button">CLICK</button>
<input type="time" id="delay">
```

Comment: I would change to `if (diff < 0) {
    sMin += 24 * 60;
    diff = eMin - sMin
  }`

Comment: fixed https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587762/10761855

Comment: You need logical difference (for example in minutes, seconds, ...) or the real calendar difference (considering date adjustment, daylight changes that day, difference in month, days, weeks)?

Comment: What you want to in your difference do you want total work hour ? if yes then why have you taken input time instead of text ?

Comment: Can you check my answer again please? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54587762/10761855

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have change your code slightly. The explanation is, let your start time is 10:00 and end time is 09:00. Now think with clock wise. the time had to go to 9:00 with 24 hours. So the calculation is difference between 24 and 10 hours and add the rest of the time.

D = E + (24 - S)

```js
function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function diffTime(start, end) {
  var s = start.split(":"),
    sMin = +s[1] + s[0] * 60,
    e = end.split(":"),
    eMin = +e[1] + e[0] * 60,
    diff = eMin - sMin;
    
  if (diff < 0) {
    diff = eMin + (24 * 60 - sMin); /* You had to caculate with 24 hours */
  }
  var h = Math.floor(diff / 60),
    m = diff % 60;
  return "" + pad(h) + ":" + pad(m);
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('delay').value = diffTime(
    document.getElementById('timeOfCall').value,
    document.getElementById('timeOfResponse').value
  );
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="timeOfCall">
<input type="time" id="timeOfResponse">
<button type="button" id="button">CLICK</button>
<input type="time" id="delay">
```

Comment: It is pleasure to help you. Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Date object to calculate the difference in time. Since you are only interested in the time, you can use any date to construct a valid date string. The reason why you are getting 10 hours is because there is no date to show that it is 1am the following day (this is from my understanding of your question).

You can do something like below to get the job done.

```
const pad = num => (num < 10) ? `0${num}` : `${num}`;

const addADay = (start, end) => {
  const sHour = parseInt(start.split(':')[0], 10);
  const eHour = parseInt(end.split(':')[0], 10);
  return (eHour < sHour);
};

const diffTime = (start, end) => {
  const startDate = new Date(`2019/01/01 ${start}:00`);
  const endDate = addADay(start, end) 
    ? new Date(`2019/01/02 ${end}:00`) 
    : new Date(`2019/01/01 ${end}:00`);
  const diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
  const hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
  const min = (diff - (hours * 3600000)) / 60000;
  return `${pad(hours)}:${pad(min)}`;
}

console.log(diffTime('08:00','09:00')); // returns 01:00
console.log(diffTime('23:00','01:30')); // returns 02:30
```

Comment: `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss`  is not a date in ISO-8601 format so the result may be unexpected.

Comment: From my experience, "-" causes issues on certain browsers (Safari). Even, this format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss causes error in the time portion. If you remove the 'T' you will get invalid date.

Comment: The correct ISO format is `2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 0):

The most important part in the required algorithm is finding if the end date is tomorrow.
based on your code here is a [working example](https://codverter.com/src/webeditor?query=1411d9be-241e-46d9-b876-da797d927498) with my suggestion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="time" id="timeOfCall">
    <input type="time" id="timeOfResponse">
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="diffTime()">CLICK
    </button>
    <input type="time" id="delay">
    <script>
      function pad(num) {
        return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
      }
      function diffTime() {
        var start = document.getElementById("timeOfCall").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("timeOfResponse").value;
        // start date will be today
        var d1 = new Date();
        var s = start.split(":")
        var date1 = new      Date(d1.getFullYear(),d1.getMonth(),d1.getDate(),s[0],s[1],0,0);
        var s2 =  end.split(":")
        // end date
        if(s2[0] < s[0])
        {
          // its tommorow...
          var ms = new Date().getTime() + 86400000;
          var tomorrow = new Date(ms);
          d1=tomorrow;
        }
        var date2 = new      Date(d1.getFullYear(),d1.getMonth(),d1.getDate(),s2[0],s2[1],0,0);
        var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        var msec = diff;
        var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
        msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
        var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
        msec -= ss * 1000;
        alert(hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss);
      }
      document.getElementById("timeOfCall").defaultValue = "23:30";
      document.getElementById("timeOfResponse").defaultValue = "01:30";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simpler way to look at the problem which satisfies all of your test cases, try your all test cases if any case fails then tell me i will fix it.

you just take the hours first and then check if is am or pm and then simply count the minutes.

```js
function diffTime(start, end) {
   var s = start.split(":");
   var e = end.split(":");
   var dHour;
   var dMinute ;
   var startHour = parseInt(s[0]);
   var endHour = parseInt(e[0]); 
   var startMinute = parseInt(s[1]);
   var endMinute = parseInt(e[1]);
   
   // For counting difference of hours

   if((startHour>12 && endHour>12) || (startHour<12 && endHour<12))
   {
    
    if(startHour<endHour)
    {
     dHour = endHour - startHour;
    }
    else if(startHour>endHour)
    {
     dHour = 24 - ( startHour - endHour);
    }
    else
    {
     dHour = 24;     
    }
   }
   else if(startHour>12 && endHour<=12)
   {
    dHour = (24 - startHour) + endHour;
   }
   else if(startHour<=12 && endHour > 12)
   {
    dHour = endHour - startHour;
   }
   else 
   {
    dHour = 24
   }


   // For Counting Difference of Minute

   if (startMinute>endMinute) 
   {
    dMinute = 60 - (startMinute - endMinute);
    dHour = dHour - 1;
   }
   else if(startMinute<endMinute)
   {
    dMinute = endMinute - startMinute;
   }
   else
   {
    dMinute = 0
   }

   return dHour + " Hours " + dMinute + " Minutes";
  }

  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('delay').value = diffTime(
    document.getElementById('timeOfCall').value,
    document.getElementById('timeOfResponse').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="timeOfCall">
<input type="time" id="timeOfResponse">
<button type="button" id="button">CLICK</button>
<input type="text" id="delay">
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function diff(t1, t2) {
  
  const day = 86400000;

function pad(num) {
   return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

    let time1 = t1.split(":").map(el => parseInt(el));
    let time2 = t2.split(":").map(el => parseInt(el));

    let zero = (new Date(1990, 0, 1, 0, 0)).setMilliseconds(0)
    let aaa = (new Date(1990, 0, 1, time1[0], time1[1])).setMilliseconds(0)
    let bbb = (new Date(1990, 0, 1, time2[0], time2[1])).setMilliseconds(0)


    let diff =  day -Math.abs(aaa - bbb)<Math.abs(aaa - bbb)?day -Math.abs(aaa - bbb):Math.abs(aaa - bbb)


    return `${pad(Math.round(diff/1000/60/60))}:${pad(Math.abs(Math.round(diff/1000/60%60)))}`;
}

console.log(diff("09:00", "08:00"));
console.log(diff("23:30", "01:30"));
console.log(diff("01:30", "23:30"));
```

Comment: Working on hours difference by using milliseconds seems way too complicated to have a clear, satisfying solution.

Comment: setMilliseconds it's how i can get timestamp of time